# Stopping a thread from another class using flags - Python/ChromeDriver

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Threads are quite difficult for me. I can't quite wrap my head around how to stop a thread when some event occurs. Its difficult for me, because in the event occurs at the end of a for loop and also involves a browser.

This method here is supposed to continuously check for a flag

```
def Stop(self, event):
    myClass.worker.terminate = True
    if myClass.worker != None:
        while myClass.browser!=None:
            if myClass.worker.taskfinished:
                myClass.worker.stop()
                myClass.browser.quit()
                myClass.worker = None
                break
            else:
                pass
```

This condition occurs at the bottom of this for loop which is part of a different method:

```
 for i in range(scraperow, numrows):
     myClass.taskfinished = False
            domain = sheet.cell_value(i, 2)
            prevdomain = sheet.cell_value(i-1,2)
            name = sheet.cell_value(i,0)
            result = ""
            if domain==prevdomain and result=="CATCH-ALL":
                worksheet.write(i, 3, "Catch all")
                wbook.save(file)
            else:
                wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 500)
                inputName = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "form-search-name")))
                inputName.send_keys(name)
                inputDomain  = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "form-search-domain")))
                inputDomain.send_keys(domain)

                norbertsearch = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "search")))
                norbertsearch.click()
                starttime = time.time()


                wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 500)
                selector = "div[class=\"text-center displayed\"] h3"
                rslt = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, (selector))))
                result = rslt.text

                if result == "SUCCESS":
                    waittwo = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 5)
                    email = rslt.find_element_by_xpath('following-sibling::div/a')
                    email = email.get_attribute('href')
                    email = email.split(":")[1]
                    worksheet.write(i, 3, email)
                    wbook.save(file)

                elif result == "NOTHING FOUND":
                    worksheet.write(i, 3, "Nothing found")
                    wbook.save(file)
                elif result == "I'M TIRED":
                    worksheet.write(i, 3, "Over search limit")
                    wbook.save(file)
                    dlg = wx.MessageBox("Norbert is tired and has exhausted his searches for the day. Try again later.", "Ask Alfred", wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
                    break
                elif result == "OH MAN, I BROKE MY ANKLE":
                    worksheet.write(i, 3, "Server error")
                    wbook.save(file)
                elif result == "CATCH-ALL":
                    worksheet.write(i, 3, "Catch-all")
                    wbook.save(file)
                myClass.taskfinished = True
```

Unfortunately its blocking up the thread, making things kind of hairy. How can I gracefully have the thread wait until its gotten a result and then stop the thread?